# Is it possible to import variables in a dust file

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, configuration, dust.js

I just finished my dust templates (default.dust file which is used in login.dust, and all the other pages) I  was wondering if it is possible to import variables from a js file ?

For example I would like to import a variable date from a js file which would go in my footer with the copyright, or maybe some external links, etc.. basically some constant or variable that I can import in my dust templates.

Is it possible ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for **context globals**.

Ref: http://www.dustjs.com/guides/contexts/#context-globals

To add globals to your context, pass an object to your `dust.context()` invocation:

```
var context = dust.context({ "footerCopyrightYear": 2016 });
context = context.push({ pageData: {...} });
...
dust.render(tmpl, context, function(err, out) { ... });
```

In this example, `footerCopyrightYear` will be available in every template that uses this context.

So, if you want all your pages to share the same context globals, externalize the context creation:

```
var context = require('global-context'); // this file exports a Dust context w/ globals
contextForPage = context.push({ /* data for this page */ });
dust.render(tmpl, contextForPage, ...);
```

Comment: I ended up making an helper which uses my constant file. Thank you for your help.